# the correct syntax for CSV Customer IMPORT? (from 1.3.1 to 1.9.1)

Tags: importexport

I've spent so many days trying to figure this out...

I EXPORTED customers on a Magento 1.3.1 version, got the CSV file but when I try to IMPORT it into a 1.9.1. version - it gives the following Error:

> Can not find required columns: email, _website
>           Please fix errors and re-upload file

The file has a website column and an Email column as far as I can see. I've tried adding the _website column and fill it all in with "base" but it does not seem to help. Also tried to rename the "website" parametr to "_website" but it makes no difference. I have base setup as the code for the main store. I appreciate any suggestions very much!

Comment: Try creating some sample customer data in 1.9.1 (if none exist), then do an export (try reimport it to 1.9.1 to make sure it work) then compare the 1.9.1 export with 1.3.1

Comment: This is my guess, but it's may be looking at `prefix or suffix` of your database too, if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

When you import data using Magento Import Export Functionality and Migrate from the One Version to Another version please follow the below steps.

**Step 1:** First Export the Both Version File and Identify What are changes in `Headers`. Because It will may differ Version to version.

**Step 2:** Once you identify which Header are Changes or Updated Then Export the Latest data File From Old Version.

**Step:3:** Open That File in `notepad` or  `Noted ++` OR `EXCEL` And Changes the Header Name as per New Version. Sometimes Boolean Values also changes so also check values and update CVS file.

**Step 4:** Once all Changes are done. Try to Upload CSV file on Latest Version and Check if you got this error Message or not.

> Can not find required columns: email, _website Please fix errors and re-upload file

**Stps 5:** If you not Found that error  then you can import data.

NOTE: Before do any changes on live site please test on environment.